# Why does $|dz|=-ir\frac{dz}{z}$ when $|z|=r$?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms

Sometimes I want to compute a line integral over some circle $|z|=r$, where I have $|dz|$ instead of $dz$ given to me.

Reparametrizing with $z=re^{it}$, it follows that $dz=rie^{it}dt=izdt$. But I always read that
$$
|dz|=|iz|dt=|z|dt=|z|\frac{dz}{zi}
$$
so $|dz|=-ir\frac{dz}{z}$. In the first equality, why does $|dz|=|iz|dt$ instead of $|iz||dt|$? Why doesn't the absolute value extend to the $dt$ as well?

Comment: The absolute value extends to the $dt$ ($=d\phi$) as well; but when you integrate with respect to increasing $t$ then $|dt|=dt$. You could also compute the circumference of the circle by integrating "the wrong way around", but then you would have to take care of $|dt|=-dt$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $t$ is already a real number and it's conventional to integrate with an increasing $t$, i.e.$\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt$ with $a\leq b$.

Answer (score 1):

If a line integral is stated as $|dz|$, then it should be understood as integral of a function with respect to a measure (as opposed to the integral of a $1$-form). Such an integral does not depend on orientation. Therefore, it would be more correct to  use $|dt|$ in place of $dt$ in the computation you quoted. The authors probably meant for $t$ to be increasing, in which case $|dt|$  and $dt$ are the same thing.